# Change YouTube iframe src with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change a YouTube video iframe source with jQuery, but looks like running into cross origin issue. My jquery code:

```
var videourl = $(".videourl").html();
$(".actualyoutube iframe").attr('src',videourl);
```

iframe gets new src value, but no video is displayed. Any ideas?

**extended explanation:**

There is a popup div with embeded youtube video

```
<div class="youtubepopup">
    <div class="closeyoutube">X</div>
    <div class="actualyoutube">
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a certain td which contains a new src url. There is no other place or way to get this url except from this td.

```
<td class="videourl">//youtube.com/whatevervideo</td>
```

And there is a script that should add src on open popup and remove on closing.

```
var videourl = $(".videourl").html();
$(".youtubecap").click(function() {
  $(".actualyoutube iframe").attr('src', videourl);
  $(".youtubepopup").fadeIn('slow');
});
$(".closeyoutube").click(function() {
  $(".youtubepopup").fadeOut('slow');
  $(".actualyoutube iframe").removeAttr('src');
});
$(".youtubepopup").click(function() {
  $(".youtubepopup").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

p.s. now that i laid it out, user3385530 is probably right

Comment: Error in console? Is `videourl` embed url version? You should provide minimalistic sample online to replicate your issue

Comment: Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2ISrpNM-0s' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Comment: So set src using embed URL version //www.youtube.com/embed/S2ISrpNM-0s

Comment: that's what i use, but for certain reasons, i need the destination to be pulled from a div.

Comment: Couldn't you provide concrete sample of what you are talking about?! Youtube doesn't let you display its own page in iframe, that's why you need to use embed URL. And I don't see why is this related to any DIV.If your users are passing youtube URL, then you need to parse them to embed version, using regex or any string replace methods or maybe start using youtube API

Comment: added extended explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot show pages from www.youtube.com inside an iframe. The correct way is to use their video embed codes inside your web page. IFrame embeds are easier, the URL you need to display in an iframe looks like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID_GOES_HERE
```

Just place an iframe such as this inside your web page:

```html
<div class="actualyoutube">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID_GOES_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Finally, assuming you are able to extract video id from the URLs using jQuery, you can use this to display videos*:

```
var videoid = "S2ISrpNM-0s";
$(".actualyoutube iframe").remove();
$('<iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
    .attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoid)
    .appendTo(".actualyoutube");
```

<sup>* Changing the `src` property of an iframe that is already displaying a YouTube video did not work; I therefore suggest destroy-iframe-recreate-iframe approach.</sup>

Comment: same Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2ISrpNM-0s' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="service-video-media">
<iframe id="main-play" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uTcj2v85y34" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="video-list">
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/uTcj2v85y34/1.jpg" video-id="uTcj2v85y34" />
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/jRuR4GaSsBI/1.jpg" video-id="jRuR4GaSsBI" />
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/ec7aQPLSBsU/1.jpg" video-id="ec7aQPLSBsU" />

<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/uTcj2v85y34/1.jpg" video-id="uTcj2v85y34" />
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/jRuR4GaSsBI/1.jpg" video-id="jRuR4GaSsBI" />
<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/ec7aQPLSBsU/1.jpg" video-id="ec7aQPLSBsU" />
</div>

</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


        jQuery('.video-list img').on('click',function () {

            var videoId = jQuery(this).attr('video-id');
            var videoUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId;
            jQuery('#main-play').attr('src',videoUrl);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because page is parsed and only on refresh with new ulr will happen.

You need to use ajax to pre-load the page with new url and then to set iframe.