# Javascript: Rewrite youtube iframe related links urls

Tags: javascript, youtube

i embedded a youtube video on my website.  how can i rewrite the related urls to example.com/watch of youtube.com/watch?  I guess with Javascript .

I did read [Change YouTube iframe src with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723720/change-youtube-iframe-src-with-jquery)

thank you, ill be sure to +1 your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: So what did you learn from the link you posted and what is the problem?

Comment: the link just changes the src url i m trying to rewrite the URLs (related videos) in the iframe